# Scanner nextLine issue in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Just one question: why I must type `answer = in.nextLine();` twice? If this line is single the program doesn't work as expected. Without second line the program doesn't ask you to enter a string.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "Yes";

        while (answer.equals("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Enter name and rating:");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            int rating = 0;

            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                rating = in.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error. Exit.");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Rating: " + rating);
            ECTS ects = new ECTS();
            rating = ects.checkRating(rating);
            System.out.println("Enter \"Yes\" to continue: ");
            answer = in.nextLine();
            answer = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Bye!");
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not need to write that in twice. o.o

Comment: The `nextInt()` leaves behind a new line character. Your first `nextLine()` will gobble it up. The second `nextLine()` will read your `yes` data

Comment: @Zhuinden - he is using `nextInt()`, he will have to .

Comment: @TheLostMind oh, so it's like the issues with `scanf` in C. I always use `BufferedReader` so I haven't run into it like that. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Zhuinden - Scanner is usually used for *parsing*, `FileReader/BufferedReader` are usually used for *reading*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scanner-Object has an internal cache.

1. You start the scann for `nextInt()`.
2. You press the key <kbd>1</kbd>
3. You press the key <kbd>2</kbd>
4. You press <kbd>return</kbd>

Now, the internal Cache has 3 characters and the scanner sees the third character(<kbd>return</kbd>) is not a number, so the `nextInt()` will only return the integer from the 1st and 2nd character (<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>=12).

5. `nextInt()` returns 12.

Unfortunately the <kbd>return</kbd> is still part of the Scanner's cache.

6. You call `nextLine()`, but the Method scans its cache for a `newline`-marker that has been kept in the cache from before the `nextInt()` call returned.
7. The `nextLine()` returns a 0-length-string.
8. The next `nextLine()` has an empty cache! It will wait until the cache has been filled with the next `newline`-marker.

### reset()

There is a more elegant way to clear the cache instead of using `nextLine()`:

```
in.reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using nextInt() this method only grabs the next int it doesn't consume the \n character so the next time you do nextLine() it finishes consuming that line then moves to the next line.